# Get back to number 1 position for keyword

Tags: seo, google, ranking, google-ranking

Our site is prikkabelled.nl. We deal in prikkabel which is Dutch for (Illumination cable). We used to have the number one spot for the keyword `prikkabel` for almost a year, but we dropped to the second spot on the 8th of July 2017. How to determine what was the exact cause of this? We had some downtime of a few hours around that day, but according to Matt Cutts of Google, this is not a contributing factor for SE position. How tom more accurately determine the reason behind the shift from number 1 to number 2 spot?

Comment: See also: [What are the best ways to increase a site's position in Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2/what-are-the-best-ways-to-increase-a-sites-position-in-google)